# How can I reverse a column in Notepad++/sublime text?

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3, reverse

Is it possible to reverse multi line in Notepad++?

Example:

```
'Charouine'=>'charouine'
'Reggane'=>'reggane'
'In Zghmir'=>'in-zghmir'
```

Would change to

```
'charouine'=>'Charouine'
'reggane'=>'Reggane'
'in-zghmir'=>'In Zghmir'
```

Thank you advance

Comment: Ctrl-F "=>" ... Then tap the right arrow key. Now hold shift and ctrl and tap the right arrow key until you reach the end of the line. Then ctrl-x to cut the selection, hold ctrl and tap left until you reach the end of the line. Ctrl-v to paste. Hold shift and ctrl and tap right arrow until your reach "=>". Now cut and paste the selection to the end of the line (move your cursor again by holding ctrl and tapping right)

Answer (score 4):

In Notepad++ you could use `^('[^']*')(=>)('[^']*')$` as search pattern and `$3$2$1` as replace pattern when having regular expressions checked as search mode.

This makes use of a regular expression, that matches the left side into a first capturing group, `=>` into a second and then the right side into a third. In the replace this order is just reversed. You could replace again and have the original order restored.

Comment: It should be needless to mention, but the same RegEx works in Sublime Text…